# How to change module of a class in Python?

Tags: python, module

module1 have funcion make_class.
module2 calls it this way:

```
Foo = make_class('Foo')
```

or this:

```
setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'Foo', make_class('Foo'))
```

But in either case we have `<class 'module1.Foo'>`
how to assign this class to module2: `<class 'module2.Foo'>`? (I need this to fulfill the requirements of SQLAlchemy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Foo.__module__ = __name__
```

Change the module name explicitly. You can have the `make_class` function handle this if you have it take a module name argument for the new class's `__module__` attribute.